# Create popup "toaster" notifications in Windows with .NET

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, desktop

I am using .NET and am creating a desktop app/service that will display notifications in the corner of my Desktop when certain events are triggered. I don't want to use a regular Message Box b/c that would be too intrusive. I want notifications to slide into view and then fade out after a few seconds. I am thinking of something that will act very much like the Outlook alerts that one gets when a new message arrives. The question is: Should I use WPF for this? I've never done anything with WPF but will happily try it if that's best means to the end. Is there a way to accomplish this with regular .NET libraries?

Comment: I think that somehow it's possible with regular .Net, Infragistics managed to do it: http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/windesktopalert.aspx#Overview

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I meant. People, please share your thoughts. I am only looking for general direction, not a detailed how-to. Thx.

Comment: here is one that has been on codeProject for a while.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/taskbarnotifier.aspx

will take less than 5 days.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

WPF makes this absolutely trivial:  It would proably take ten minutes or less.  Here are the steps:

1. Create a Window, set AllowsTransparency="true" and add a Grid to it
2. Set the Grid's RenderTransform to a ScaleTransform with origin of 0,1
3. Create an animation on the grid that animates the ScaleX 0 to 1 then later animates the Opacity from 1 to 0
4. In the constructor calculate Window.Top and Window.Left to place the window in the lower right-hand corner of the screen.

That's all there is to it.

Using Expression Blend it took about 8 minutes me to generate the following working code:

```
<Window
    x:Class="NotificationWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="Notification Popup" Width="300" SizeToContent="Height"
  WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent">

  <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0,1" >

    <!-- Notification area -->
    <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="Beige" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="10">
      <StackPanel Margin="20">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5">
          <Bold>Notification data</Bold><LineBreak /><LineBreak />
          Something just happened and you are being notified of it.
        </TextBlock>
        <CheckBox Content="Checkable" Margin="5 5 0 5" />
        <Button Content="Clickable" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
      </StackPanel>
    </Border>

    <!-- Animation -->
    <Grid.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
              <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
              <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
              <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
              <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>

    <Grid.RenderTransform>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>

  </Grid>

</Window>
```

With code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

public partial class NotificationWindow
{
  public NotificationWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() =>
    {
      var workingArea = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
      var transform = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice;
      var corner = transform.Transform(new Point(workingArea.Right, workingArea.Bottom));

      this.Left = corner.X - this.ActualWidth - 100;
      this.Top = corner.Y - this.ActualHeight;
    }));
  }
}
```

Since WPF is one of the regular .NET libraries, the answer is yes, it *is* possible to accomplish this with the "regular .NET libraries".

If you're asking if there is a way to do this without using WPF the answer is still yes, but it is extremely complex and will take more like 5 days than 5 minutes.

Comment: This is great. Works like a charm. Thank you! Impressive how little code it took.

Comment: + Cool, you've just save me some time as well! Thanks)

Comment: Not sure if this is needed, but I added a Completed event to the opacity animation, and in the code behind I added "this.Close();".  Otherwise the window would always stay open.  May mess up an app that closes based on the last window closing.

Comment: One can also use `System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea`, so no need to use the windows.forms dll (as noted in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620488/how-to-set-the-location-of-wpf-window-to-the-bottom-right-corner-of-desktop)

Comment: Apologies for the re-run of this question; But @Paul, could you ~please~demonstrate how you added the completed event?

Comment: @NewAmbition, in case still haven't figured out, I did, sort of, but don't know if it's what Paul used. Anyway, here it goes - use the Completed event of the animation that animates that Opacity

Comment: PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) returns null here, any idea what could cause that?

Comment: @TheGeekZn, completed event here:
<Storyboard Completed="Storyboard_Completed">

code behind:
private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            this.Close();
 }

Comment: I'm new to storyboard...how can I make the notification to stay a little longer ? say 5 seconds

Answer (score 20):

**I went ahead and created a CodePlex site for this that includes "Toast Popups" and control "Help Balloons".  These versions have more features than what's described below.  https://toastspopuphelpballoon.codeplex.com.**

This was a great jumping off point for the solution that I was looking for.  I've made a couple of modifications to meet my requirements:

- I wanted to stop the animation on mouse over.
- "Reset" animation when mouse leave.
- Close the Window when opacity reached 0.
- Stack the Toast (I have not solved the problem if the number of windows exceeds the screen height)
- Call Load from my ViewModel

Here's my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Foundation.FundRaising.DataRequest.Windows.NotificationWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="NotificationWindow" Height="70" Width="300" ShowInTaskbar="False"
    WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" 
    Background="Transparent">

<Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0,1" >
    <Border BorderThickness="2" Background="{StaticResource GradientBackground}" BorderBrush="DarkGray" CornerRadius="7">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="24"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.Column="0" 
                   Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                   Source="Resources/data_information.png" 
                   Width="40" Height="40" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

            <Image Grid.Column="2" 
                   Source="Resources/error20.png"
                   Width="20" 
                   Height="20" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   ToolTip="Close"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   Cursor="Hand" MouseUp="ImageMouseUp"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15"
                       Text="A Request has been Added"/>

            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    FontSize="15"
                    Margin="0,-3,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Content="Click Here to View" 
                    Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}"/>
        </Grid>            
    </Border>

    <!-- Animation -->
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryboardLoad">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:2" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:8" BeginTime="0:0:5" Completed="DoubleAnimationCompleted"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardLoad"/>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardFade"/>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryboardFade">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:8" BeginTime="0:0:2" Completed="DoubleAnimationCompleted"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>

    </Grid.Triggers>

    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

The Code Behind

```
public partial class NotificationWindow : Window
{
    public NotificationWindow()
        : base()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Closed += this.NotificationWindowClosed;
    }

    public new void Show()
    {
        this.Topmost = true;
        base.Show();

        this.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
        this.Closed += this.NotificationWindowClosed;
        var workingArea = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;

        this.Left = workingArea.Right - this.ActualWidth;
        double top = workingArea.Bottom - this.ActualHeight;

        foreach (Window window in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
        {                
            string windowName = window.GetType().Name;

            if (windowName.Equals("NotificationWindow") && window != this)
            {
                window.Topmost = true;
                top = window.Top - window.ActualHeight;
            }
        }

        this.Top = top;
    }
    private void ImageMouseUp(object sender, 
        System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void DoubleAnimationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsMouseOver)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The call from the ViewModel:

```
    private void ShowNotificationExecute()
    {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(
            () =>
            {
                var notify = new NotificationWindow();
                notify.Show();
            }));
    }
```

The Styles referenced in the XAML:

```
     <Style x:Key="LinkButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <TextBlock>
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </TextBlock>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GradientBackground" EndPoint="0.504,1.5" StartPoint="0.504,0.03">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFDD5A7" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFCE79F" Offset="0.567"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

**UPDATE:** I added this event handler when the form is closed to "drop" the other windows.

```
    private void NotificationWindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Window window in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            string windowName = window.GetType().Name;

            if (windowName.Equals("NotificationWindow") && window != this)
            {
                // Adjust any windows that were above this one to drop down
                if (window.Top < this.Top)
                {
                    window.Top = window.Top + this.ActualHeight;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does the NotificationWindowClosed work? It's not referenced anywhere else in the code

Comment: Sorry about that.  I've added the missing code.  This has been a work in progress, and I missed that in the last update.

Comment: Works perfectly! Can you explain a little more on the meaning of " I added this event handler when the form is closed to "drop" the other windows." What do you mean "drop"?

Comment: Basically, when the window reaches 0 opacity and closes, I wanted the windows that are above to "drop" down towards the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 8):

```
public partial class NotificationWindow : Window
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    public NotificationWindow()
        : base()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() =>
        {
            var workingArea = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
            var transform = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice;
            var corner = transform.Transform(new Point(workingArea.Right, workingArea.Bottom));

            this.Left = corner.X - this.ActualWidth;
            this.Top = corner.Y - this.ActualHeight;
        }));
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4d);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    }
    public new void Show()
    {
        base.Show();
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //set default result if necessary

        timer.Stop();
        this.Close();
    }

}
```

The above code is refined version @Ray Burns approach.  Added with time interval code. So that Notification window would close after 4 seconds..

Call the Window as,

```
NotificationWindow nfw = new NotificationWindow();
nfw.Show();
```

Comment: @Gopichandar I couldn't understand Gopi

Answer (score 2):

I used the answer above to design my own notification window that is a bit more user friendly, in my opinion, and uses a few techniques that took me a little while to figure out. Sharing in case it helps anyone else out there.:

1. Added MouseEnter event trigger to immediately set window opacity to 1 so a user does not have to wait for the window to fade into full view.
2. Added MouseLeave event trigger to fade the window opacity to 0 when the user moves the mouse out of the window.
3. Added MouseUp (mouse click) event trigger to immediately set window opacity to 0 to hide the notification window.
4. If you have to Show() and Hide() the notification window multiple times, then below method also resets the Storyboard at the end so that the next Show() operation starts the operation from the start and there is no glitch in the animation.

XAML:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="ToastNotificationWindow"
    Title="Notification Popup"
    Width="480"
    Height="140"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Transparent"
    BorderThickness="0"
    Topmost="True"
>


    <Grid Background="Transparent" Name="ToastWindowGrid" RenderTransformOrigin="0,1">

        <Border Name="ToastWindowBorder" BorderThickness="0" Background="#333333">

            <StackPanel Name="ToastWindowStackPanel" Margin="10" Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Image Name="ToastLogo" Width="100" Height="100" Source="D:\Development\ToastNotification\resources\Logo-x100.png"/>

                <StackPanel Name="ToastMessageStackPanel" Width="359">

                    <TextBox Name="ToastTitleTextBox" Margin="5" MaxWidth="340" Background="#333333" BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" Text="Toast Title" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>

                    <TextBox Name="ToastMessageTextBox" Margin="5" MaxWidth="340" Background="#333333" BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True" Foreground="LightGray" FontSize="16" Text="Toast title message. Click to start something." HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>

                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>

        </Border>

        <Grid.Triggers>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="StoryboardLoad">
                        <Storyboard Name="ToastAnimationStoryboard">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:20" Value="1"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:23" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardMouseLeaveFadeOut"/>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="StoryboardMouseEnterFadeIn">
                        <Storyboard Name="ToastAnimationStoryboardMouseEnterFadeIn">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardMouseLeaveFadeOut"/>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="StoryboardMouseLeaveFadeOut">
                        <Storyboard Name="ToastAnimationStoryboardMouseLeaveFadeOut">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseUp">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardMouseEnterFadeIn"/>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardMouseEnterFadeIn"/>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardMouseLeaveFadeOut"/>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardMouseLeaveFadeOut"/>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="StoryboardMouseClickFadeOut">
                        <Storyboard Name="ToastAnimationStoryboardMouseClickFadeOut">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                    <SeekStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardLoad"/>
                    <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardLoad"/>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>

        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

public partial class ToastNotificationWindow
{
    public ToastNotificationWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() =>
        {
            var workingArea = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
            var transform = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice;
            var corner = transform.Transform(new Point(workingArea.Right, workingArea.Bottom));

            this.Left = corner.X - this.ActualWidth - 10;
            this.Top = corner.Y - this.ActualHeight;
        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
Stream iconStream = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Assets/ic_instant_note_tray.ico")).Stream;
notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(iconStream);
notifyIcon.Text = string.Format(Properties.Resources.InstantNoteAppName, Constants.Application_Name);
notifyIcon.Visible = true;
notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(5000, "tooltiptitle", "tipMessage", ToolTipIcon.Info);
notifyIcon.Visible = false;
notifyIcon.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the calling thread must be sta because many ui components require this, while writing following code under system.timers.timer elapsed event

```
Window1 notifyWin = new Window1();
bool? isOpen = notifyWin.ShowDialog();
if (isOpen != null && isOpen == true)
{
     notifyWin.Close();
}
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
notifyWin.ShowDialog();
```

under window1 constructor:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() => { 
        var workingArea = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea; 
        var transform = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice; 
        var corner = transform.Transform(new Point(workingArea.Right, workingArea.Bottom)); 
        this.Left = corner.X - this.ActualWidth - 100; 
        this.Top = corner.Y - this.ActualHeight; 
    })); 
}
```