# WPF 'Toaster' Popup - How to close?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I'm using the following to create 'toaster' style pop-ups:
[Create popup "toaster" notifications in Windows with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034741/create-popup-toaster-notifications-in-windows-with-net)

Unfortunately, after the message "disappears", there is still a 'task' in the taskbar.  After showing multiple popups, there is a separate 'task' for each popup that was opened, all stacked on top of each other.

How can I close these after the opacity animation has completed?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own toast implementation, perhaps you can find use of it! It's very simple, all you do is:

```
ToastMessage.Show("My message", "My Title");
```

And you're done! :) I'll keep updating it until I think it's perfect, but modify it as you wish! I'm yet to add things like animations and sound effects.

Here is the link:
[GitHub WPFToastMessage](https://github.com/CrashIT14/WPFToastMessage)

Comment: Thanks for posting this sample. It helped me find the above problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746869/toaster-window-does-not-close-in-task-manager/40803907#40803907

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and it's pretty easy!

I changed this (minus space at beginning):

< Storyboard>

To this:

< Storyboard Completed="Storyboard_Completed">

Then in the 'properties' pane under events, I double-clicked the new event that was auto-added and got this:

```
private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

And simply added:

```
    this.Close();
```