# Simple Taskbar NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, wpf, taskbar, notifyicon

I have a software that needs to trigger a little popup image by the taskbar. I have found some classes to help my cause, however, they're too complex and I wanted to ask here first if there's a better option for my scenario.

This is what I found: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon

But I don't need all those functions. I can't seem to find a simple way to achieve my goal.

All I need is a 200x100 rectangle image to pop-up by the bottom right corner, and open a URL when right clicked. It should open the webpage using the system's default browser. However, I need to do a few more things in addition, so a method like Object_clicked() would really help me a lot. Simply, I want a clickable notification image to popup for x seconds, but I don't know an easy way to do it.

Should I try to go with the link I found, or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Note that NotifyIcon also has a nuget package: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification

Comment: WPF doesn't wrap the native [Shell_NotifyIcon()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) winapi function like Winforms does with its NotifyIcon class.  They just omitted it, plenty of WPF programmers that stepped in and wrote a wrapper for it.  If you don't like their work then, by all means, wrap it yourself.  Many have done before you for the reason you quote in your question.  Can't trust nobody's code until you understand what it does.

Comment: You could see this article it may help u<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034741/create-popup-toaster-notifications-in-windows-with-net