# prevent more than one tray icon in c#

Tags: c#, trayicon

I am developing an application in c#.net,and for that i am writing code to display icon in a system tray,and whenever a new message arrives the balloon tooltip will be shown there,which has click event which will open new message arrived,everything works fine,but the problem is i am getting multiple numbers of icon generated in system tray,which shuld be only one,how can i prevent it?i found on internet how to dispose them,but couldn't find way to prevent more than one.or is there any better way to show notifications for newly received message..please help me if you know the solution..

Comment: A little code might help.

Comment: ...and where's your code that is creating your icons?

Answer (score 2):

There are better custom solutions available see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034741/create-popup-toaster-notifications-in-windows-with-net) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22876/WPF-Taskbar-Notifier-A-WPF-Taskbar-Notification-Wi) for some examples.

However, System Tray doesn't refresh automatically. If you show/hide multiple system tray icons, it can mess the tray up. Normally all disposed icons will disappear when you mouse hover. However, there is a way to refresh the system tray programmatically. Reference [here](http://maruf-dotnetdeveloper.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/c-refreshing-system-tray-icon.html).

**Note :** SendMessage function, sends the specified message to a window or windows. The SendMessage function calls the window procedure for the specified window and does not return until the window procedure has processed the message.

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, int lParam);


    public void RefreshTrayArea()
    {
        IntPtr systemTrayContainerHandle = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null);
        IntPtr systemTrayHandle = FindWindowEx(systemTrayContainerHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "TrayNotifyWnd", null);
        IntPtr sysPagerHandle = FindWindowEx(systemTrayHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "SysPager", null);
        IntPtr notificationAreaHandle = FindWindowEx(sysPagerHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "ToolbarWindow32", "Notification Area");
        if (notificationAreaHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            notificationAreaHandle = FindWindowEx(sysPagerHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "ToolbarWindow32", "User Promoted Notification Area");
            IntPtr notifyIconOverflowWindowHandle = FindWindow("NotifyIconOverflowWindow", null);
            IntPtr overflowNotificationAreaHandle = FindWindowEx(notifyIconOverflowWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "ToolbarWindow32", "Overflow Notification Area");
            RefreshTrayArea(overflowNotificationAreaHandle);
        }
        RefreshTrayArea(notificationAreaHandle);
    }


    private static void RefreshTrayArea(IntPtr windowHandle)
    {
        const uint wmMousemove = 0x0200;
        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(windowHandle, out rect);
        for (var x = 0; x < rect.right; x += 5)
            for (var y = 0; y < rect.bottom; y += 5)
                SendMessage(windowHandle, wmMousemove, 0, (y << 16) + x);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much..for your reponse,but can you please tell me where to put this code and how to call it out..?

Comment: @Software_developer: Probably in the class where you show the notification. Refresh the tray before or after you show a new notification.